# Activating a ASP Multiview control's view from other page without querystring/session

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview

I was looking for an alternative that may be used to activate a multiview control of other page without passing a querystring/session variable.

Basically, my Home.aspx page has a link that takes us to a specific page say "NewPage.aspx". The NewPage.aspx page has a multiview control that has three child views.

I want to click on the link of the Home.aspx and go to NewPage.aspx with `MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex=1`. Please remember that I do not want to pass any querystring variable as that link already contains some encrypted data as querystring and adding another variable can cause the data to corrupt. Maintaining a session isn't a solution as well because the application is quite big.

Any inbuilt method that can activate that view? (I don't seem to be talking practical but any help is really appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how navigate to this page I would wire up a button event (I prefer to do so in OnInit). Something like this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    this.btnlinkclick.Click += new EventHandler(btnlinkclick_Click);
}
void btnlinkclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
}
```

This should work for you.